# Unable to create clientid-secret in Azure Active Directory

Tags: python, azure, rest, azure-active-directory

I am trying to generate a New ClientID and Secret for an Application in Azure Active Directory using `client_credentials` flow using code below.

The application used to run this script has `Application.ReadWrite.All`, `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permissions at `Application` and `Delegated` level.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Azure AD B2C Constants
application_id ='888-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx'
TENANT_ID = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx'
CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx'

# Token endpoint to get the access token
token_endpoint = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token'

# Resource URL
resource_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'

# Scopes for the Microsoft Graph API
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' ]

# Parameters to get the access token
token_data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
    'scope': ' '.join(scopes)
}

# Get access token
token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=token_data)
access_token = token_response.json().get('access_token')

# Create app registration in Azure AD B2C
create_app_endpoint = f'{resource_url}/v1.0/{TENANT_ID}/applications'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

url_password = f'{resource_url}/v1.0/applications/{application_id}/addPassword'

print(url_password)

# Construct the request body with password credentials details
password_credentials_data = {
    "passwordCredential": {
        "displayName": "System_Access_1"
    }
}

# Send the request to create password credentials
response = requests.post(url_password, headers=headers, json=password_credentials_data)

# Check the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Password credentials created successfully.")
else:
    print("Failed to create password credentials. Status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response:", response.text)
```

However, I am getting an error

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/888-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx/addPassword

Failed to create password credentials. Status code: 404
Response: {"error":{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":"Resource '888-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.","innerError":{"date":"2024-02-26T16:01:36","request-id":" ","client-request-id":""}}}
```

I have followed the approach here,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I checked in Azure Active Directory and the application exists. What could be the potential reason?

Comment: When I try `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/` it returns me with all the apps list; when I try `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/xxxx-xxxxxx` with a valid appId I receive `404` Request_ResourceNotFound

Answer (score 0):

Considering the application manifest is as below,

```
{
    "id": "e9e28b75-9236-46c3-8422-f5aebc7d6df3",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": false,
    "appId": "77b9c7ae-b4d4-4d51-b479-9bae4a0186db",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2024-02-26T14:40:35Z",
    "description": null,
    "certification": null,
    "disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
}
```

The correct URL would be,

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/e9e28b75-9236-46c3-8422-f5aebc7d6df3/addPassword`

This uses `id` and not `appId`